# Flex TextInput maxChars and pressing insert

Tags: apache-flex, insert, textinput

So I am noticing this weird behavior with a TextInput in Flex when I have the maxChars property set on it. For example, maxChars="1".

If you have this set and have 1 character in the TextInput and then press another key nothing will happen because the max characters are already in there. However, if you press the Insert key and then press another key, that character will show up in the TextInput, leaving you with 2 characters in a TextInput which only allows 1 character max.

I believe this is happening in all TextInput's not just custom ones.

Anyone have an idea of how this could be fixed? Some method I can override in a custom TextInput to override this behavior?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could listen for [TextOperationEvent.CHANGE](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/supportClasses/SkinnableTextBase.html#event%3achange) and then just strip extra character(s) from the .text property

Comment: Would listening for TextOperationEvent.CHANGING be better? That way I could listen for it and if we already have the maximum allowed characters entered I could call event.preventDefault()?

Comment: I was considering suggesting that, but i havent tested it so didnt want to pass on possibly incorrect info. Assuming preventDefault stops the text being added (and not some other behaviour), its definitely a more elegant solution.